# Hive: Multiple files in one partition

Tags: hadoop, hive

Hive: Can I add partition with few locations?

For example, will the following query work?

```
alter table data 
add partition (year = 2013, month = 11, day = 18) 
LOCATION '/path1/a.avro,/path2/b.avro..';
```

Comment: can you find a way to add multiple files into same partition?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. If the partition already exists in Hive (HDFS directory), then you don't need to run any hive alter commands.  Just use hadoop -fs put ..

For example you have a hive partition table test (partitioned by dt):
  /user/hive/warehouse/test/dt=20131216
with files:
  /user/hive/warehouse/test/dt=20131216/1.avro
  /user/hive/warehouse/test/dt=20131216/2.avro
Now if you have a new avro file: 3.avro then just run the hadoop fs -put command and hive will be able to see the new file automatically.